# How to Cast a Text property from a textbox in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm new to the site and I'm coding in VB.net. I need to clear all the `textbox` from a Form but the problem is that the `.text` propierty don't pop up! I've been reading about it and the solution seems to cast the textbox using `Ctype`. Can someone help me with this please? The code for my method:

```
 Dim ctrl As Control

        For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
            If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Then
                ctrl.text = "" 'This is the error, thanks!'
            End If
        Next
```

It seems that the problem is that the textbox is nested under a series of `div` elements: this is the example of my html code:

```
<div class="col-md-3"><!--Inicia primer contenedor-->
              <center><img src="../../Recursos/Imagenes/proveedor.png"/ class="rounded"></center>
               <h4>Opciones</h4>
               <asp:TextBox ID="tbBuscarProv" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
               <asp:Button ID="btBuscarProv" runat="server"  Width="100px" Text ="Buscar" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-block" />
               <asp:Button ID="btNuevoProv" runat="server" Width="100px" Text="Nuevo" CssClass="btn  btn-primary btn-block" />
               <asp:Button ID="btLimpiarProv" runat="server" Width="100px" Text="Limpiar" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-block" />
               <asp:Button ID="btCerrarProv" runat="server" Width="100px" Text="Cerrar" CssClass="btn  btn-primary btn-block" />
           </div><!--Termina contenedor de imagen y búsqueda (primer contenedor)-->

           <div class="col-md-9" id="Formulario" ><!---Inicia segundo contendor-->

               <div class="row"><!--Inicia la primera fila-->
                   <div class="col-md-4">
                       <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">Id. Proveedor:</span>
                           <asp:TextBox ID="tbIdProveedor"  runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ></asp:TextBox>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div><!--Termina la primera fila-->
```

I'm also using `Boostrap`I don't know if this is affecting the `inner-code`somehow

Comment: `For Each tb As TextBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)` tb is already a `TextBox` Type, so no need to cast it

Comment: Go into your project properties and turn on `Option Strict` (under the Compile heading, I think). Once you've done that, run your project again. It will fail to start with a lot of errors. You'll need to fix them. At the very least, it should be `.Text` not `.text`. You should _always_ have `Option Strict` turned on, it gives you ~20% faster execution and shows a lot of problems at compile time instead of at runtime. Incidentally, there's a setting to have this turned on by default. (Tools->Options->Projects and Settings->VB Defaults). Welcome to SO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using DirectCast:

```
DirectCast(ctrl, TextBox).Text = ""
```

CType is more to be used when converting between *different* data types, while DirectCast is to be used when the object you're casting is of the same type as, inherits or implements from, the class you're casting to.

---

**EDIT:**

Try changing the if statement to:

```
If ctrl.GetType() Is GetType(TextBox) Then
```

Comment: Hi!, thanks for the response, I try to do it with a test but it doesn't work.. I'm using it wrong?  Dim ctrl As Control

        For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
            If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Then
                DirectCast(ctrl, TextBox).Text = " "
            End If

        Next

Comment: @AlexLlanez : Does it throw an error? Also, remove the `Dim ctrl As Control` line.

Comment: No, but the text does not change to a blank space for example

Comment: @AlexLlanez : Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code :

```
For Each Control In Me.Controls
    If Control.GetType() Is GetType(TextBox) Then
        CType(Control, TextBox).Clear
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET you should rather use `Page.Controls` instead of `Me.Controls`:

```
For Each ctrl As Control In Page.Controls
    If ctrl.GetType() Is GetType(TextBox) Then
        DirectCast(ctrl, TextBox).Text = ""
    End If

    'Check for child controls
    If ctrl.HasControls() = True Then
        For Each subctrl As Control In ctrl.Controls
            If subctrl.GetType() Is GetType(TextBox) Then
                DirectCast(subctrl, TextBox).Text = ""
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next
```

**EDIT:**

Updated code to check inside child controls.

---

**EDIT 2:**

Alternate code:

```
For Each ctrl As Control In Page.Controls
    For Each subctrl As Control In ctrl.Controls
        If TypeOf subctrl Is TextBox Then
            DirectCast(subctrl, TextBox).Text = ""
        End If
    Next
    If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Then
        DirectCast(ctrl, TextBox).Text = ""
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Try this code under my click method and doesn't work either I been thinking to do it the old fashion way and reset control by control. But to be honest you've been an amazing community, glad I join to SO.

Comment: @AlexLlanez : I added an alternate code, try that too. :)

Comment: And also, try the codes using both `Me.Controls` and `Page.Controls`. Just so that we've covered the possibility of one of them not working.

Comment: try it with both options, no one works :( I need to advance with the rest of the project so old fashion here we go. I'm going to improve this part of the code when the rest is donde, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @AlexLlanez : Okay, but I'm not giving up yet! I currently do not have access to a computer... But when I do, I'm gonna reconstruct this and see if I can get it working :). -- Also, here's a little tip for you (unless you're already doing this): Instead of copying the "old fashion" code two times, put it all in a sub (i.e `Private Sub ResetControls()`) and call that sub every time you need to reset the controls.

Comment: I'm not giving up yet either as soon as this is figure it out I'm going to share with you and the rest of the community! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!!! So it seems that because all my controls are nested in several `div` elements we need to be more especific in the code so no `Me.Controls` or `Page.Controls` instead I used the name of the `Form`and it worked just fine, here is the code:

```
For Each ctrl As Control In FormProveedores.Controls
            If ctrl.GetType() Is GetType(TextBox) Then
                DirectCast(ctrl, TextBox).Text = ""
            End If
        Next
```

So in this code `FormProveedores.Controls` did the trick thank you so much all for your support on this topic I learn a lot today! :D

Comment: The trick was make the `div` runat server to be able to point at it with the code @VisualVincent or maybe just a rookie mystake on my part

Comment: Yes, it has to be run on the server-side in order for the code behind code to modify it.